# how to use boldface (from another package) while using ebgaramond font

Tags: fonts, bold, times, eulervm, ebgaramond

I wanted to use the ebgaramond font and I can get it to work using 'latex' however, there is no boldface font available with this package. Is it possible to set up the LaTeX document such that it will get the boldfaced font from some other package (eg. times or euler, etc.)?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I can't help asking: why do you want to do this? It will be typographically horrible. I think it would be better to perhaps substitute the sans or bold sans font for bold serif. It is really not a good idea to use a different serif font for bold. Also, there is no really clean way of doing this for (pdf)LaTeX though you could obviously do it for Lua/XeLaTeX if you really wanted to. If you absolutely wanted to, I think it would be best to use substitute font definitions. That should work but it is pretty icky.

Comment: Use Garamond Extended (`garamondx`) instead! If you are a TeX Live user run `getnonfreefonts`, as MiKTeX user install with the Package Manager.

Comment: My usual comment: using boldface with Garamond is like Charlton Heston wearing a wristwatch when playing Ben Hur.

Comment: According to https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2163.1544077914.4481.ctan-ann@ctan.org `ebgaramond` now supports bold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## EBGaramond with Monotype Garamond Bold

This example mixes EBGaramond with Monotype's Garamond in pdfLaTeX. Note that this code will **not** compile as written for you. You would need to substitute a suitable alternative for the bold Garamond I've used. (Or configure TeX support for it on your machine, if you have the same font.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pdfmapfile{+mgm.map}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
\ProvidesFile{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}

\expandafter\ifx\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\EBGaramond@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\EBGaramond@@scale{s*[\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{nw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{
     <-> mgmb8t
  }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sc}{
     <-> mgmbc8t
  }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{
     <-> mgmb8t
  }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{
     <-> mgmb8t
  }{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OSF/m/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sc}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/nw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\kant[1]

\noindent{\bfseries \kant[1]}

ABC \textbf{ABC} abc \textbf{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image: EBGaramond and Monotype Garamond bold]

## EBGaramond with Medium URW Garamond as Bold

This example takes the medium series from URW Garamond for bold text. You can install this using the `getnonfreefonts-sys` script which is part of TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
\ProvidesFile{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}

\expandafter\ifx\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\EBGaramond@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\EBGaramond@@scale{s*[\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{nw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{
     <-> ugmm8t
  }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{
     <-> ugmmi8t
  }{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/m/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sc}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sl }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sc}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/nw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}


\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\kant[1]

\noindent{\bfseries \kant[1]}

ABC \textbf{ABC} abc \textbf{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image: EBGaramond with URW Garamond Medium]

Note that URW Garamond includes a restricted set of font shapes in comparison with EBGaramond. So small-caps bold will be typeset in non-small-caps upright medium, for example, as there is no medium small-caps available.

## EBGaramond with Extended URW Garamond Bold

This uses fonts from `garamondx` which extends the URW families provided in `garamond`. You may wish to adjust the scaling factor, as in the other examples. Like `garamond` which provides the standard URW Garamond, `garamondx` can be installed using `getnonfreefonts-sys`.

### Olstyle Figures

[image: EBGaramond and Extended URW Garamond bold]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=1.05]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
\ProvidesFile{T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}

\expandafter\ifx\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\EBGaramond@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\EBGaramond@@scale{s*[\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\expandafter\ifx\csname zgm@Scale\endcsname\relax
 \let\zgm@@Scale\@empty
\else
 \edef\zgm@@Scale{s*[\csname zgm@Scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\def\zgm@tmp{\ifzgm@swq \def\zgm@@swq{-swq}\fi}
\let\zgm@@swq\@empty
\ifdefined\zgm@swqtrue
  \zgm@tmp
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-osf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{nw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-swash-t1
}{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-b-osfI\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-bi-osfI\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sc}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-b-osfI-sc\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scit}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-bi-osfI-sc\zgm@@swq
  }{}


\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/m/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sl }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sc}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/sw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/b/nw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/bx/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/bx/it }{}


\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\kant[1]

\noindent{\bfseries \kant[1]}

ABC \textbf{ABC} abc \textbf{abc}

\end{document}
```

### Lining Figures

Here's a variation on the example above of EBGaramond with Extended URW Garamond bold. This one using lining, rather than oldstyle, figures.

[image: EBGaramond with Extended URW Garamond bold and lining figures]

```
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=1.05,lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{T1EBGaramond-LF.fd}
\ProvidesFile{T1EBGaramond-LF.fd}

\expandafter\ifx\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname\relax
    \let\EBGaramond@@scale\@empty
\else
    \edef\EBGaramond@@scale{s*[\csname EBGaramond@scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\expandafter\ifx\csname zgm@Scale\endcsname\relax
 \let\zgm@@Scale\@empty
\else
 \edef\zgm@@Scale{s*[\csname zgm@Scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\def\zgm@tmp{\ifzgm@swq \def\zgm@@swq{-swq}\fi}
\let\zgm@@swq\@empty
\ifdefined\zgm@swqtrue
  \zgm@tmp
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-lf-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-lf-sc-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{sw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Italic-lf-swash-t1
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{nw}{
      <-> \EBGaramond@@scale EBGaramond12-Regular-lf-swash-t1
}{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{n}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-b-lf\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{it}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-bi-lf\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{sc}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-b-lf-sc\zgm@@swq
  }{}

  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{scit}{
   <-> \zgm@@Scale   T1-zgm-bi-lf-sc\zgm@@swq
  }{}


\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/m/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/m/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/sl }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{b}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{sc}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/sc }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/it }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{scit}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{sw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/sw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{nw}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/b/nw }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{scsl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/bx/scit }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-LF/bx/it }{}


\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

\textbf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

\textbf{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

0123456789

\textbf{0123456789}

\end{document}
```

## Extended URW Garamond Medium and Bold

These examples do not use EBGaramond at all. Instead, they take Speravir's advice and use the extended fonts supplied by `garamondx` for both medium and bold.

### Oldstyle Figures

[image: Extended URW Garamond (OSF)]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[osfI]{garamondx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\kant[1]

\noindent{\bfseries \kant[1]}

ABC \textbf{ABC} abc \textbf{abc}
```

### Lining Figures

[image: Extended URW Garamond (LF)]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

\textbf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

\textbf{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

0123456789

\textbf{0123456789}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!This does now work for me (on Fedora 20 linux). There are error messages:

Comment: mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mgmb8t' failed to make mgmb8t.tfm.
! Font T1/EBGaramond-OsF/bx/n/10=mgmb8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) fi
le not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.80 \noindent{\bfseries
                         \kant[1]}

kpathsea:

Comment: @user3236841 Indeed. That is expected. As I said, you would need to substitute a font you actually have. My answer shows you how to do that but unless you have Monotype Garamond installed for use with pdfTeX, you'll need to substitute an alternative. All those `mgm...` are Monotype Garamond. I don't know what you wish to use instead.

Comment: @user3236841 I've added an example using URW Garamond's medium weight for bold text. You can install this more easily by just using the script included in TeX Live, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get getnonfreefonts following: https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ but the above code does not work.Specifically, I use latex test.tex where test.tex is the above and I get no pages of output.

Comment: pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file mgm.map): cannot open font map file
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./T1EBGaramond-OsF.fd'.
kpathsea: Running mktextfm mgmb8t, etc. Not sure how to put the whole error messages because of few characters. Btw, can I use latex (instead of pdflatex).

Comment: @user3236841 The second example does not load `mgm.map` so either you are still using the code from the first example or you maybe have stale auxiliary files. Make sure the `.aux` etc. is deleted and try again. It is expected that it will overwrite the `.fd` file in your working directory. It gets recreated every time you compile (that's what the `filecontents` environment does). It is not overwriting the default one installed as part of your TeX installation.

Comment: @user3236841 I've also added a couple more examples just for completeness. Note that the last one does not use EBGaramond at all. This corresponds to Speravir's suggestion in the comments on your question.

Comment: So, I have the following error when using garamondx:(./tem1.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 zgmr-digits
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmr-digits.
mktexpk: perhaps zgmr-digits is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file zgmr-digits): Font zgmr-digits at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
How do I get around this?

Comment: @user3236841 Which example are you trying to compile? Are you sure you installed the fonts correctly using the script `getnonfreefonts-sys`? Because it sounds very much as if the fonts are not installed correctly *or* you have stale configuration files. Make sure you used the `-sys` version of the script and remove or move to a backup directory any `.texlive2013` directory you find in your home directory. (This is TeX Live - not sure about MiKTeX but if you used the script, I assume you have TL.)

Comment: I installed using sudo getnonfreefonts-sys --all and sudo getnonfreefonts-sys --lsfonts says that these packages are installed. (yes, I am using TexLive on linux -- Fedora 20). Btw, I am trying to compile the last example above. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user3236841 Are you using Fedora's TL or TL from upstream?

Comment: @cfr: Hi, I am using Fedora's TexLive.

Comment: @user3236841 What does `kpsewhich zgm.map` give? You followed the instructions at https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/? And it lists the fonts as installed?

Comment: @Speravir Indeed. That is in fact where I read that you were not a native English speaker ;). [I'm cleaning up comments a bit to keep this tidier.]

Comment: /kpsewhich zgm.map gives usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/dvips/garamondx/zgm.map;thanks!

Comment: @user3236841 Good. What about `kpsewhich zgmr-digits.tfm`?

Comment: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/urw/garamondx/zgmr-digits.tfm

Comment: @user3236841 Huh. OK. You shouldn't need to do this but just for diagnosis, try adding `\pdfmapfile{+zgm.map}` at the beginning of your preamble (after `\documentclass`). This won't work with `latex` - you'll need to use `pdflatex`.

Comment: Yes, this works! What do I need to do in order to get latex to work with this? My document needs to be in latex because I have to use epsfiles for figures.

Comment: @user3236841 So the script should have installed the map file fragment when it installed the font. But either that didn't work or something is interfering with it. Check that `kpsewhich updmap.cfg` gives you something under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local` and that you don't have any `~/.texlive2013`. Then try `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map-zgm.map` and watch for errors/problems in the output. I only asked you to add that line because whether it worked or not gives me a much better idea of what might be wrong. We can rule out a bunch of possibilities since it works.

Comment: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg is what I get. I deleted the directory ~/.texlive2013. Is that good? This creates the dvi file without errors, but  dvipdf tem1.dvi 
dvips: Font zgmb8r not found; using cmr10
dvips: Font zgmb-digits not found; using cmr10
dvips: Font zgmr8r not found; using cmr10
dvips: Font zgmb8r not found; using cmr10
dvips: Font zgmr-digits not found; using cmr10
and the pdf file does not render (as expected, i guess?)

Comment: @user3236841 What did `updmap-sys --enable Map...` do?

Comment: I get the following:Try "updmap --help" for more information.
Try "updmap --help" for more information.
m

Comment: I think you meant Map=...correct?

Comment: $ sudo updmap --enable Map=zgm.map
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: Btw, I realized that kpsewhich updmap.cfg gives me:
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg not .../texmf-local/.... is this an issue?

Comment: @user3236841 Yes, sorry. I meant `Map=`. But you are using `updmap` and that's the problem. You need to use `updmap-sys`. Currently, it is installing the fonts only in root's personal texmf tree which, obviously, does you no good at all...

Comment: Sorry, I did use updmap-sys. Here are the results: $ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=zgm.map
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/root/.texlive2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: @user3236841 If `updmap-sys` is using `/root/.texlive2013/...` then there is something seriously screwy going on. The whole *point* of `updmap-sys` (as opposed to `updmap`) is that it will not do that! You could try deleting `/root/.texlive2013` or, better, just move it somewhere as backup and seeing if that makes a difference but I don't know why it should. I can only think this is a 'feature' of Fedora's configuration but although I run Fedora on one machine, I don't use their `texlive`. Personally, I would scrap Fedora's install and use upstream's version but I realise you may not wish to.

Comment: OK, I got rid of /root/.texlive2013 and ran sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=zgm.map and got bunch of these:
updmap: generated map otf-up-noEmbed.map (from otf-up-@kanjiEmbed@.map) does not exists, not activating it!
updmap: generated map ptex-noEmbed.map (from ptex-@kanjiEmbed@@kanjiVariant@.map) does not exists, not activating it!
..
ERROR:The following map file(s) couldn't be found: morisawa.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg) otf-cktx.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg) Did you run mktexlsr?  .disable non-existent map entries using --syncwithtrees.

Comment: But this worked. I had to do the following:sudo mktexlsr and then  sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=zgm.map --syncwithtrees followed by sudo updmap-sys.

Comment: @user3236841 Try `updmap-sys --syncwithtrees` and then (if that goes OK) `updmap-sys --enable Map=zgm.map`. EDIT: It worked?!

Comment: However, my document is longer than with ebgaramond. Interesting! Also, how do I get lining of my numerals with garamondx?

Comment: @user3236841 See edited answer. I've added 2 examples with lining figures. One uses `garamondx` only. The other combines EBGaramond with the bold from `garamondx`.

Comment: thanks! Example 3 works beautifully!! I will try out the others also, but this does do what I want.

Comment: @user3236841 Please consider accepting the answer if it does indeed provide a solution which works for you. This helps other users to find it and will also get you (and me!) some reputation.

Comment: Hi, I have a new problem. And I get the following now on my actual document:kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 lmmi8
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for lmmi8.
mktexpk: perhaps lmmi8 is missing from the map file.
xdvi: Can't find pixel font lmmi8; using cmr10 instead at 600 dpi.
Is this related to the actions I took earlier to get garamondx to work? Thanks!

Comment: @user3236841 The following what? If it is a new problem, you should ask a new question, linking this one if appropriate. EDIT; Do you have Latin Modern installed? Nothing you did should cause this issue but it is fairly odd that `updmap-sys` was using `/root/.texlive2013` in the first place. Since I'm not sure why that was, I wouldn't like to say for sure...

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the following happens after doing xdvi on the document. How do I figure out if Latin Modern is installed? The following is installed: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty (This must be Latin Modern?) But interestingly, I do not get the paper to display math notation correctly using times or ebgaramond only. Something has gotten messed up. Thanks again!

Comment: So, I went back and reinstalled using getnonfreefonts (not -sys) and it seems to work now. Not sure what the problem earlier was.

Comment: @user3236841 Odd. I have no idea why that would fix a problem with Latin Modern.

Comment: Hi, I have been having this issue of late when I  read the file using xdvi: 
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+120/600 --dpi 720 zgmb8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmb8r.
mktexpk: perhaps zgmb8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

Comment: completely lost as to what the issue is: this worked fine in April and no changes have been made to the Fedora 20 system but for regular updates.

Comment: @user3236841 Everytime your package manager updates `texlive` packages which include fonts, you probably need to update the map files since you are managing these in your home `texmf` tree. At least, I imagine that's the problem. [Warning: do NOT update `garamondx` right now! Just update the map file using `updmap` or `updmap-sys` (whichever you use).]

Comment: Thanks, I did have to go back to everything and run it all again, and it works! This has been quite an educational experience for me, no doubt, and perhaps will continue to be so! Thanks again!!!!

Comment: OK, I tried to make some changes and have realized that in the boldface, "fi" is replaced by a bigger II. Why does this happen? Also, can I replace the fonts of the boldface from the gentium family which seems to be more pleasant? If so, what do I do? Many thanks again!!

Comment: I wanted to clarify this issue some more: what I am saying is that the word "efi"  can not be written in the bold face in any of these cases above (including for garamondx). I get something looking like: eII.Any suggestions as to how to get around this issue? Many thanks again!

Comment: @user3236841 Oh, dear. Yes, I'm afraid I do. You need [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215754/), I think, as your issue is [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215739/) except that you have the TeX Live version which I diagnose in my answer. You will have the fonts in your home `texmf` tree, I think. So you won't need to touch anything at the system level. This is a mess created by some combination of `garamondx`, `getnonfreefonts` (or the `-sys` version in my case) and whatever else. Unfortunately, you have to clean up by hand. If you get stuck, ask a new qn. re. Fedora.

Comment: That is, ask a new question specifically about Fedora/other Linux distro's TeX Live with `garamondx` installed using `getnonfreefonts` (rather than `-sys`). [Ping me somewhere - I can answer - but too much for comments!]

Comment: OK, where can I ping you? I tried everything listed in that sequence but no dice.

Comment: here is what i got:

Comment: this worries me:

Comment: sudo /usr/local/bin/getnonfreefonts-sys -f garamondx 
...gives:...........Updating map files (updmap-sys). Be patient...              updmap: generated map otf-noEmbed.map (from otf-@kanjiEmbed@.map) does not exists, not activating it!
updmap: generated map ptex-noEmbed.map (from ptex-@kanjiEmbed@@kanjiVariant@.map) does not exists, not activating it!etc....... 
[done] 
What is all this does not exist?

Comment: Also:      sudo mv $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/src $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/source/fonts/garamondx
mv: cannot move ‘/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local///src’ to ‘/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local///source/fonts/garamondx/src’: Directory not empty

Answer (score 7):

I would really really like to discourage you from mixing a Garamond medium-weight upright and italic font with a `Times`-like bold and bold-italics font. (Incidentally, I'm not sure why you mention `euler` in your query, as it's a pure math font and thus completely unsuited for running text.)

If you must mix and match `EB Garamond` with another Garamond, you're probably best off doing so in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Care must definitely be exercised to equalize the x-heights of the various fonts being used. In the example below, `EB Garamond` is the font for upright and *italics*, and `Adobe Garamond Pro` is used for **bold** and ***bold-italics***. There are two `\setmainfont` instructions; the first just loads `EB Garamond`, and the second uses the `Scale=MatchLowercase` font features on the Bold and Bold-Italics fonts.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex   %% xelatex works too
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainfont[BoldFeatures = {Scale=MatchLowercase},
             BoldFont = Adobe Garamond Pro Bold,
             BoldItalicFeatures = {Scale=MatchLowercase},
             BoldItalicFont = Adobe Garamond Pro Bold Italic,
             Ligatures = {TeX,Common}]
            {EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\section*{A section title}

Normal \emph{italics} {\bfseries bold} {\itshape\bfseries bold-italics}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives errors, using xelatex:"xparse/redefine-command"
*  Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu1enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)    You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
See the fontenc package documentation...                                                                                                
l.99 \ProcessOptions*

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}


\begin{document}

abc \textbf{xyz}

\end{document}
```

warns you there is no bold:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/EBGaramond-OsF/bx/n' in size <10> not avail
able
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/EBGaramond-OsF/m/n' tried instead on input 
line 7.
```

This comes from

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
```

So you could (but I wouldn't) specify a different substitution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}


\begin{document}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * cmr/bx/n }{}
abc \textbf{xyz}

\end{document}
```

use bold computer modern and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! I need this because I want a narrow font which will take less space, yet I also want to have boldface characters.

Comment: Btw, there are some fonts at this website:
http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/index.html How do I get the document to substitute the boldface from there (while keeping all the other ebgaramond fonts to be the same). Thanks!

Comment: How do I substitute with the boldfaced from garamondx (instead of computer modern as in the above example)?

Comment: If you have a package that loads those fonts just look what the internal family name is instead of `cmr`

Comment: @user3236841 You already have an example of how to do that in my answer. Confused...

Comment: @cfr: thanks! The reason i am asking is because ebgaramond seems to take less space than garamondx. So I was wondering if it is possible to only take tge boldface fonts from garamondx and substitute it in ebgaramond.

Comment: @David: can you suggest a package which can tell me what the internal family name of a font is? Thanks!!

Comment: @user3236841 you can see the fd files in the log file (the encoding and family name makes the filename) but the other answer has a fully worked example of this