# garamondx ligatures no longer work

Tags: pdftex, garamondx

I have been using the `garamondx` font package with `pdflatex` to typeset my CV for years without any problems. During my latest round of keeping it up to date, suddenly ligatures no longer want to typeset. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}
Sufficiently pacific
\end{document}
```

Result (copied from the resulting PDF):

```
Su`ciently paci∏c
```

I would argue that this is clearly incorrect. I have tried looking at the documentation, which suggests the addition of `\usepackage[full]{textcomp}` before loading, but that doesn't have any effect. I've tried using `fontenc` to change the font encoding, but always get the same result. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, but to no avail.

Every other font I've tried gets the ligatures correct. I've also tried the `ebgaramond` and `garamond` packages, but these versions of Garamond are too heavy for my taste.

Has anyone else observed this behavior? I'm using MikTeX on Windows 7

---

When I add `\listfiles` to beginning of the MWE above, the log file contains the following `garmondx`-related lines:

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\garamondx.sty"
Package: garamondx 2014/10/08 v1.092

`garamondx' v1.092. 2014/10/08 GaramondNo8 with expert features (Michael Sharpe
)

...

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+zgmx on input line 7.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\garamondx\t1zgmx.fd"
File: t1zgmx.fd 2012/10/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/zgmx.
)
("C:\Users\craigim\Documents\My Dropbox\LaTeX\Projects\GaramondMWE.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 7.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
```

Comment: I get the same. However, I see an update is available. I'm currently in the process of installing that, so fingers crossed ;).

Comment: But it doesn't... :(.

Comment: Why on earth does it require `graphicx` for god's sake?

Comment: Looks like a bug? Anybody else? By the way, I'm using TeX Live. This is a package problem, I think.

Comment: I get the ligatures and can also copy-paste without problems. Version details: `garamondx 2014/03/11 v1.07`

Comment: In miktex: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9DsGN.png

Comment: @egreg `v1.092` dated `2014/10/08` (`garamondx.sty`). Update and you, too, can probably enjoy the bug ;). If I regenerate the support files, I can get back most, but not all, of the ligatures. However, I haven't investigated further and doing this also loses a bunch of fine-tuning in the `.fd` files, for example.

Comment: The character corresponding to the `ffi` ligature is mapped to character octal 24 in `zgmr8r.tfm`, while `fi` is mapped to character octal 2 in the same font. My feeling is that you have a wrong version of `zgmr8r.tfm`. Is the output correct in print or also in print it's like the one you show?

Comment: [With the packaged files](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3wQhb.png). And [with regenerated files](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CYdwr.png). [TeX Live 2014 is current; `garamondx` is current.]

Comment: @egreg I regenerated the `tfm`s and, while that improves things, `ffl` is still missing.

Comment: @cfr It seems that the virtual font has been damaged; or `zgmr8r.tfm` has gone awry.

Comment: @egreg Or there are too many of them. Where is `zgmr8r.tfm` in your tree? I seem to have two copies...

Comment: @egreg Can `getnonfreefonts` ***uninstall*** them? Or do I do that by hand? The damn thing has installed multiple, identically-named files.

Comment: @cfr I don't think `getnonfreefonts` can uninstall fonts. Do it manually and always use `getnonfreefonts-sys` (as super user).

Comment: @egreg Sorry. I meant `getnonfreefonts-sys`. I can't convince it `garamondx` is not installed, though. Do you know where it stores this information? (I've cleared everything I can find, disabled the map file, and updated the database.) [I don't use it as root, though ;).]

Comment: OK. I forced it to reinstall `garamondx` even though it was really, really, really sure that it was really, really, really there. And, lo and behold: [ligatures return](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj8ej.png).

Comment: I use MiKTeX and have no problem (garamondx v. 1.092).

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled using the MikTeX package manager, and it didn't help. How do I go about manually removing all vestiges of the font package and starting fresh? I just had to apply to a job with a CV in `times` font.

Comment: @Bernard Worth checking your tree. I don't know if the same issues apply but on TL, it would work if you didn't have an older version (or you had only a recent old version) but it still makes a mess.

Comment: @Bernard Can you explain how to do this for MiKTeX? I've given instructions for TeX Live...

Comment: @cfr: I did nothing special. I simply update regularly and it seems to work. I suspect a problem concerning synchronisation of the data base of files.

Comment: @craigim: Which version of `garamondx` do you have?

Comment: @Bernard No. At least on TL, it is definitely not that. The package is installing at least something things in the wrong places and files have been moved between `public` and `urw` without removing the stale files. (As well as the source being in `src` rather than `source/fonts/garamondx`.)

Comment: @Bernard If you download the TDS archive from CTAN, you can see that it has the source in the top-level directory `src` which should not exist at all. The remaining issues are caused by the moves of files from `urw` to `public`, which don't get cleaned out. That is, it isn't a database problem - the problem is that there are two lots of identically named files on the system and in that database. [EDIT: It may be a database problem on MiKTeX. I wouldn't know about that.]

Comment: @Bernard How can I check what version I have? While I was posting this question, just to be sure, I uninstalled the `garamondx` package using the MikTeX `Package Manager (Admin)` and then reinstalled (the manager gives a package date of 2014-10-21). So I'm using whatever MikTeX thinks the latest version is. I've been using the font continually for years and the problem only recently popped up, presumably after doing a general package update using the MikTeX update manager.

Comment: @cfr: I also have an `src` directory, containing files used by `fontinst`, but this is no problem for me. So perhaps I have no problem because I have no urw files, and the `urw` package is no more part of MiKTeX (I think perhaps it was once — that might be an explanation for the O.P. Thus he/she should remove everything from the old garamond package).

Comment: I've emailed the package author but it is a mess only partly of `garamondx`'s making. @craigim Can you put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and edit your question to show the full paths to files associated with `garamondx`? Look especially for `public` versus `urw` sub-directories of `fonts`.

Comment: @Bernard The files are not from `garamond`. There is no problem having `garamond`. The `src` will not cause problems but it is incorrect. It ought not be there. (If every package did that, you'd have an undifferentiated set of all source files in one directory.) `garamondx` used, I suspect, to install as `urw` and has switched to `public`. The problem is ***not*** with `urw/garamond`. It is with `urw/garamondx` coexisting with `public/garamondx`.

Comment: @craigim:  So your version is OK. Did you have the old `urw` package, from Walter Schmidt? That might be an explanation, as it contained a garamond package. I'm not sure it was part of MiKTeX once, but it's possible.

Comment: @Bernard I have both URW `garamond` and `garamondx`. That is NOT a problem. The problem has nothing whatsoever to do with having `urw/garamond`.

Comment: @cfr: Well, I have no idea then. It works fine for my MiKTeX system and not the O.P.'s system??!! Perhaps checking the contents of psfonts.map?

Comment: Search results in C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\ for psfonts.map: No items match your search.

Comment: You must have other relevant lines. I'd like to see which `.tfm` files it uses, for example, which `.vf` files etc.

Comment: That said, if you don't have `psfonts.map` at all, perhaps the problem in your case has nothing to do with mine and you just need to run `updmap`?

Comment: I can't test now in miktex but first check for updates also with the user update manager. And run updmap. The map is called  nowadays *pdftex.map* not psfonts.map.

Comment: @cfr running `updmap` worked!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Isn't `psfonts.map` for `dvips`? (On TeX Live, anyway.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Return of the Ligatures]

The current package works. The current installation script apparently screws up and fails to *uninstall* all of the old version. I suspect this is because the `tds` file for the package is apparently somewhat messy but, also, because `getnonfreefonts-sys` mistakenly assumes that the packages it installs will be well-behaved. But the current installation still leaves a mess - just it leaves a working mess, rather than a non-working one which is improvement, of a sort.

These instructions should work for TeX Live. Somebody will hopefully modify them for MiKTeX.

Switch to the user you use to manage your local `texmf` tree. (This will be root on many systems. Be very careful, if yours is among them!)

```
cd $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)
pwd
```

Make sure you really have switched directories.

Make a temporary directory somewhere if you would prefer to move files rather than removing them [recommended].

```
mkdir ../garamondx-incase
```

It should *not* be in the directory you are currently in or in any sub-directory of that directory.

```
updmap-sys disable zgm.map
```

Now you want to move all traces of `garamondx` from this directory tree to your 'incase' directory:

```
fonts/afm/public/garamondx
fonts/afm/urw/garamondx
fonts/enc/dvips/dvips/garamondx
fonts/enc/dvips/garamondx
fonts/map/dvips/dvips/garamondx
fonts/map/dvips/garamondx
fonts/tfm/public/garamondx
fonts/tfm/urw/garamondx
fonts/type1/public/garamondx
fonts/type1/urw/garamondx
fonts/vf/public/garamondx
fonts/vf/urw/garamondx
source/fonts/garamondx
src **** CHECK CONTENTS FIRST ****
tex/latex/garamondx
```

[If you think I've missed something, please let me know.]

```
mktexlsr $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)

getnonfreefonts-sys -f garamondx
```

Make `garamondx` behave slightly more civilly:

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/source/fonts
mv $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/src $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)/source/fonts/garamondx
mktexlsr $(kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL)
```

[If I've missed something, let me know! The combination of a messy `garamondx` and an insufficiently careful script makes for one ***very, very badly behaved thing***.]

Be careful. It is a mess. Note, too, that the `.sty` file is problematic, as well, although it does work. It is loading completely irrelevant packages, as well as using document-level commands.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what the necessary steps were, but I uninstalled all fonts with the string "garamond" in either the package name or description, then I had to go in and erase a bunch of empty directories, then I reinstalled `garamondx` and the final _coup de grace_ was to run `updmap`. With that, your test sentence hits all the correct ligatures and more importantly, my CV compiles without error. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Well I can confirm that after an update with getnonfreefonts garamondx in texlive was messed up. Happily in my case (as I had used getnonfreefonts instead of getnonfreefonts-sys and have my local files elsewhere) the fonts where alone in TEXMFHOME and I could simply delete the tree and reinstall. In miktex everything worked out-of-the box. Did you inform the texlive team and the author of garamondx about the problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I emailed the author about both the misplacement of the source (which doesn't stop anything working but is non-TDS) and this issue, but I think this issue is possibly not the package author's fault, He said that he uses `public` whereas the CTAN packager uses `urw` (but not now?), and that the latter never answers his emails. I'm not sure who the right person to contact about it is. (The TDS stuff will get cleaned up and so will the style file, I think, but the issue causing stuff to break seems to depend on several people and I can't disentangle them!)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just got a notification in my CTAN RSS feed that the `garamondx` package has been updated to v1.093a with the announcement text: "Corrections to paths in source folder of tds, plus added instructions in README for removing previous version prior to updating."

Comment: @craigim I tried the update and the ligature problem is still there. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg Did you remove the old files?

Comment: @cfr I didn't. Then removed everything in directories called `garamondx` and reinstalled. Fail.

Comment: @egreg I had to disable the map file before reinstalling and I had to force the reinstallation.

Comment: @cfr No good. When I do `pdflatex -recorder`, the `.tfm`, `.vf` and `.pfb` files live in `.../public/garamond`. FOUND! There was a stray `zgm.map` left!

Comment: @egreg Let me guess: `dvips/dvips/garamondx`? Check under `fonts/enc` as well as that has the same problem.

Comment: @cfr Exactly. Thanks! Those were in the wrong place to begin with!