# garamondx doesn't typeset double quotes correctly.

Tags: csquotes, garamondx

When I use the garamondx package, latex no longer typesets double quotes correctly (see code below). Instead, double quote left is replaced with a superscript v symbol, and double quote right is replaced with a subscript 1. I have also tried using the csquotes package to include double quotes, but the problem persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass [twoside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osfI]{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx, cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin {document}

Test of ``quotes.''

Test of \enquote{quotes.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're possibly suffering of the same (or similar) problem explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215739/garamondx-ligatures-no-longer-work In my test the quotes appear as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Uninstalling and reinstalling garamondx and then running updmap seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I voted for closing as duplicate, hoping you don't mind. The question will still be useful for others, as it will point to the solution.